# Is it possible to start backgroung app when the screen is turned off ? How?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Is it possible to start a background app when a broadcast receiver is activated and the screen is off ?
I am not running any service in background just want to wake up and unlock the screen and show an activity from an app that is in the background.
At the moment I am able to wake up and unlock the screen only if the app was in foreground when the screen turned off.

Comment: You need to implement a foreground service for this. Else it would be difficult.

Comment: difficult or impossible ?

Comment: definitely not impossible. just a bit difficult especially if not used to the way the android documentation is being written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching and hair pulling it turns out there are a few things that really matter when one wants to have an activity shown directly above the lockscreen (or better said unlock and show the activity).

When creating a channel (for android 8+) one needs to define the visibility of the channel as: **channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);**
this will show it above the lock screen.

Also the notification needs to have proper visibility like: **.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)**.
But to actually start the activity you need to set the fullscreenIntent:
**builder.setFullScreenIntent(pendingI, true);**

If needed and the notification is important and if you need the above then you have very big chances you also need the priotity set:
**.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)**.

See the below code examples...

```
requestCode = 587;
NOTIFICATION_ID = 111;
private void launchFullScreenNotification(Intent activityIntent) {
    PendingIntent pendingI = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext.getApplicationContext(),
            requestCode, intentTinta, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setLights(Color.WHITE, 2000, 3000)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
            .setContentTitle("blink blink")
            .setContentText("check me out...")
            // this is important...
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
            // this is important...
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    // very important, this is the activity intent to launch automatically
    builder.setFullScreenIntent(pendingI, true);
    Notification incomingCallNotification = builder.build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notifMan = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext);
    notifMan.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, incomingCallNotification);

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) mContext.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);

    if (!powerManager.isInteractive()) { // if screen is not already on, turn it on
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "alarma:SCREENLOCK");
        wl.acquire(60000);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "alarma:SCREENLOCK");
        wl_cpu.acquire(60000);
    }
}

private void createChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channel_name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        mChannel.setDescription(channel_description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
        // channel, if the device supports this feature.
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            mChannel.setAllowBubbles(true);
        }
        // this is important...
        mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
}
```

Also if you want  the activity to be shown above the lockscreen you might be interested in adding either into the manifest something like:

```
android:turnScreenOn="true"
android:showOnLockScreen="true"
```

Alternatively you might need to add in the **onCreate** method after the **setContentView()** something like:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        this.setTurnScreenOn(true);
        this.setShowWhenLocked(true);
    } else {
        final Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    KeyguardManager keyguardManager=(KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) ;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
    }
```

Since I just discovered how this code works I might discover some other things along the way so bear in mind I might update this answer after some time...

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible but there are now restrictions after Android 10.
One way it used to be possible was by having a Broadcast receiver for an alert and then start the activity with `startActivity`.
[Now this is possible only in special cases](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)

**Exceptions to the restriction**

Apps running on Android 10 or higher can start activities only when one or more of the following conditions are met:

- The app has a visible window, such as an activity in the foreground.
- The app has an activity in the back stack of the foreground task.
- The app has an activity in the back stack of an existing task on the
  Recents screen. Note: When such an app attempts to start a new
  activity, the system places that activity on top of the app's
  existing task but doesn't navigate away from the currently-visible
  task. When the user later returns to the app's task, the system
  starts the new activity instead of the activity that had previously
  been on top of the app's task.
- The app has an activity that was started very recently.
- The app called finish() on an activity very recently. This applies
  only when the app had either an activity in the foreground or an
  activity in the back stack of the foreground task at the time
  finish() was called.
- The app has a service that is bound by the system. This condition
  applies only for the following services, which might need to launch a
  UI: AccessibilityService, AutofillService, CallRedirectionService,
  HostApduService, InCallService, TileService, VoiceInteractionService,
  and VrListenerService.
- The app has a service that is bound by a different, visible app. Note
  that the app that is bound to the service must remain visible for the
  app in the background to start activities successfully.
- The app receives a notification PendingIntent from the system. In the
  case of pending intents for services and broadcast receivers, the app
  can start activities for a few seconds after the pending intent is
  sent.
- The app receives a PendingIntent that is sent from a different,
  visible app.
- The app receives a system broadcast where the app is expected to
  launch a UI. Examples include ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL and
  SECRET_CODE_ACTION. The app can start activities for a few seconds
  after the broadcast is sent.
- The app is associated with a companion hardware device through the
  CompanionDeviceManager API. This API allows the app to start
  activities in response to actions that the user performs on a paired
  device.
- The app is a device policy controller running in device owner mode.
  Example use cases include fully managed enterprise devices, as well
  as dedicated devices like digital signage and kiosks.
- The app has been granted the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission by the
  user.

Comment: It would seem that "The app receives a notification PendingIntent from the system. In the case of pending intents for services and broadcast receivers, the app can start activities for a few seconds after the pending intent is sent." is what I am looking for. Thanks Is there some example code around for that ?

Comment: I think that `notification PendingIntent` are intents stored as pending in a notification. They are triggered when the user clicks on them so it makes sense to be able to open an activity if the intent was for a service o a broadcast recevier. Normally the pending intent in a notifications are for Activities so it is expected behaviour to be able to open an Activity